# Creating a program that counts the amount of adding the numbers from 1 to 100 (for example: 1+2+3+4+5....and so on), using the WHILE loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a homework to create a program that counts the amount of adding the numbers from 1 to 100 (1+2+3+4+5.....), using the while loop!

I tried the code provided down below! But the problem with it is that I already know the amount, but I need to make the program calculate it!

Code I tried:

```
amount = 0

while amount <= 5050:
    amount += 1

print("The amount is: " + str(amount))
```

Comment: first, forget that you know the result. Focus on *until what number* i am calculating the sum. See if that rings any bells. Can you write that as a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're doing now is adding 1 until you reach 5050. Instead, you want to add the numbers 1 through 100. The solution, then, is to have two variables - one representing the total sum so far (this can be `amount`), and another representing the number you're adding. You continue to increase the amount you add, for each iteration, until you've added 100 to your running total.

```
amount = 0
to_add = 1
while to_add <= 100:
    amount += to_add
    to_add += 1
```

A more traditional way to do this would be to use a `for` loop, which can let you iterate over "the list of numbers from 1 through 100" (which you get by using the built-in `range()` function):

```
amount = 0
for i in range(1, 101):
    amount += i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
sum=0
while i<=100:
    sum+=i
    i+=1
print(sum)
```

Comment: Add some descriptions.